# Another chameleon question

Tags: support, specific-question, vote-to-close, asking-questions

This question: [Is there a tool which can resume video conversion?](https://superuser.com/q/385876/101850) seems to be about… well, video conversion, but as the most-upvoted answer indicates, user’s right p0rblem lies everywhere. What should we do with this? Close as „not a real question”?

Answer (score 5):

It's a perfectly fine question. It's asking how he can convert a video, without someone interrupting him.

The top voted answer provided an alternative that didn't involve other software. The answerer just found another issue in the question, that helped him solve the problem.

**tl:dr** The question is perfectly fine.

Comment: Except is isn’t about converting video. If the title had been „How do I convert video without someone interrupting me?”, it would have been fine.

Comment: @kinokijuf I think you are being too nit-picky with it. The answer found an alternative to a program.

Comment: The problem is simply that the OP is asking for his attempted solution, not the actual issue. I've asked him to clarify what he really wants, because in the end it'd be easier to just ask "How do I convert video without someone interrupting me?", like @kino suggested. However, the OP has to make that decision. We don't have to do that for him, and that's why I think there's nothing we should do about the question.

Answer (score 2):

You have made a mistake I think, in thinking that the most upvoted answer must be where the problem is.

The problem (as I see it) is that there is no tool that supports what the OP wants to do. This  does not mean that it is not possible (my the best of my knowledge it *is* possible) but rather that no-one has written a program that does it.

Even if the answer involved dodging the situation (getting another user account etc) that does not mean that the question should be closed. It just means that it is hard to directly do what the OP is asking for.